# How to persist Excel cell formats in C# Interop?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am reading an Excel sheet programmatically using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in C#.
I am able to read it row by row and converting each row to a string arrray. Then, I am adding these rows to a DataTable.
Every thing works fine except the one of the column in the Excel contains Date values, and when I fetch it from the Excel Range object and cast it to string array, the date values gets converted to some sort of decimal numbers.
For e.g.-

- If the date value is '6/4/2016  8:14:39 PM', I get the value as '42522.5224305556'
- If the date value is '5/27/2016  1:10:12 PM', I get the value as '42517.54875'

Below is my code-

```
private System.Data.DataTable GetTicketsFromExcel(string excelFilePath)
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dtblTickets = new System.Data.DataTable();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Worksheet ws = new Worksheet();
        Workbook wb = null;

        try
        {
            wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(excelFilePath, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                               Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                               Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                               Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                               Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                               Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                               Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Sheets.get_Item(1);
            Range usedRange = ws.UsedRange;
            Range rowRange;
            string[] lsRow = null;

            for (int i = 1; i <= usedRange.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                dtblTickets.Columns.Add(usedRange.Cells[5, i].Value.ToString());
            }

            string sortColumn = "Reported On";
            string sortDirection = "DESC";
            dtblTickets.Columns[sortColumn].DataType = typeof(DateTime);

            for (int row = 6; row <= usedRange.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                //dtblTickets.Columns.Add()
                rowRange = usedRange.Rows[row];
                object[,] cellValues = (object[,])rowRange.Value2;
                lsRow = cellValues.Cast<object>().Select(o => Convert.ToString(o)).ToArray<string>();
                dtblTickets.Rows.Add(lsRow.ToArray());
            }
            dtblTickets.DefaultView.Sort = sortColumn + " " + sortDirection;
            dtblTickets = dtblTickets.DefaultView.ToTable();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            wb.Close();
            excelApp.Quit();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ws);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp);
            ws = null;
            wb = null;
            excelApp = null;
        }
        return dtblTickets;
    }
```

Please note-

- I don't want to use OLEDB to read and export this
- I want to able to read the Excel row by row (without extracting each cell value and converting them)
- I don't want to convert/format the original Excel document data

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: can you please post demo of your excel file

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually now I am able to do it- lsRow[8] = DateTime.FromOADate(double.Parse(lsRow[8])).ToString();

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure, if you want to solve the problem this way, but one way is to change the property of the Cells (or the whole row or column) in Excel.

- Right click on a Cell
- Format Cells
- Under "Number" select Category "Text" for the Cells.

I've tested it and it worked.

Comment: Sorry, I actually mentioned that I don"t want to format the Excel file manually.